# Concerning Converting Text file to Binary File c++

Tags: c++, binary

I've been at it all night just trying to get a simple program to read in a text file and then copy it/write it back into a binary format.

My code looped through the text doc, got the data, put it in the buffer and wrote it back out. Heck I even hard coded the data I wanted to be written out in binary.

I used fstream, ofstream, example: fp1.open("student.dat",ios::binary);

and was reading up on several different sites such as: 
http://www.functionx.com/cpp/articles/serialization.htm

http://www.cppforschool.com/tutorial/files2.html

and I had working code, but when I open the .bin file in my Notepad++ I saw that my text data still looked like text and wasn't really 'converted' over to any hexdecimal format, or anything really. Numbers were, and I double checked to see if they were accurate by y'know, a little website where you can type in the number and it spits out the hex.

I was so fed up as to why my text wasn't converting that I destroyed all my code and tried to start over.  *hence the lack of examples"

So, my question, finally is,  why wasn't the text changing in any way, is this normal for a binary file and using this method?   I've even used pre-made coding examples and it all came out the same way.  Am I just expecting it to all look like 1's and 0's and really it's not and it was all really working?

My main project is to convert an .OBJ file to binary data, but really how should I be looking at this?  How should this binary file look?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!
Thank you!

Comment: If you want to see 1's and 0's in your file, then you have to write 1's and 0's to your file.

Comment: Text characters are just a sub-set of binary characters - what "conversion" were you expecting?

Comment: You want a text file that contains 0s and 1s as its only characters. That's not what a binary file is. A binary file is simply a file that is not treated as text when reading from it - it is treated as a sequence of bytes. Text editors are specifically for reading and editing text files.

Comment: "My main project is to convert an .OBJ file to binary data" - hmmmm... `.obj` files **are** binary

Comment: I guess I was expecting everything to be in Hex. I'm reading now that ::binary doesn't change the ASCII, it just writes it in.      So my question will have changed to: " How do I go about converting/serializing a text file into an unreadable binary file format? "

Comment: and is this something that I should be worrying about? the .OBJ files I'm looking at changing are mainly numbers, but I still don't feel like how I am going about it is the right way.

Comment: @CodingImagination What do you mean be unreadable?  Encrypted?

Comment: not encrypted,  the raw binary data as hex values

Comment: The hex values are a matter of interpreting the binary data.  You could display it in binary or octal too.  Search the web for "Hex editor"

Comment: The OBJ file is a binary file that has a specified format or layout.  An executable is also a binary file with a different layout.  How do you need to convert your OBJ file?  Do you want to view it in Hex?

Comment: So is the actual question - "How do I read a file as binary and output the data as hex in a text file?"

Comment: I think I've found a good answer from all of this, and realized everything is working as it should! I tested it with different data types and saw the difference!  Thank you all for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I was just using Chars and string and wasn't seeing a difference. Once I started using other data types, it became apparent that there was a change.   I understand that .OBJ and .txt are binary file types, i just expected a bigger change.   I used cplusplus.com and reviewed what I needed to know more of. Thank you for trying to help I guess!